# How do I update attachment urls after changing site domain

Tags: uploads, attachments, migration

I recently moved my site from `https://subdomain.example.com` to `https://example.com`.

Now all my attachments still point to
`https://subdomain.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/file.mp3`

even though now "live" at
`https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/file.mp3`

Is there some way to globally update all attachment urls?

Answer (score 0):

[GO LIVE UPDATE URLS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/go-live-update-urls/)

Try out this plugin which has worked well for me in the past.

Answer (score -1):

I will paste solution from an article. You can change paths with sql queries, but before, **make a backup of your database first**.

> Make sure you have the new database selected, then run some SQL updates and replacement commands on the tables notably, wp_options, wp_posts, wp_postmeta.
> Use the code as below and swap in your old and new URLs, no trailing slashes. Also if necessary change the table prefix values where applicable (ie wp_ )

Here are sql queries, which you should fire in your database manager (usually phpmyadmin). Find there SQL tab. In these sql queries you need to replace urls with your old and new. And if you have different table prefixes (not wp_), change them too, after the word UPDATE:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');
```

[image: MySQL change and update WordPress URLs]

[source link](https://wpbeaches.com/updating-wordpress-mysql-database-after-moving-to-a-new-url/)

Comment: This will break any serialised values.

Comment: He told nothing about serialised values, by default paths are simple strings

Comment: Meta and option values can be serialised and contain URLs. If any of these exist in their database then this query will break their site.

Comment: `replace(meta_value,'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');` will replace value from one to another. If there is no `http://www.oldurl` - nothing will change. So it will break nothing.